Cloud function triggered by Firestore event
I have deployed cloud function (Gen 2) that is supposed to be triggered each time a new document in "messages" collection is created in my Firestore DB. Than the "test" data field with hardcoded string is supposed to be added to this document. I can see that the function is actually triggered on new doc creation, but I am keep getting TypeError:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore.js:297:115)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:113:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Cannot figure out what is the issue.
This is the code that is being executed:
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

const functionsRegion = "europe-west1";

exports.testtrigger = onDocumentCreated({region: functionsRegion}, "/messages/{documentId}", (event) => {
  logger.log("Inside test_trigger function");

  const test = "Function was triggered on new document creation.";
  const documentRef = getFirestore().doc(event.data.value.name); 
  return documentRef.set({ test }, { merge: true }); 
});

of I was also trying to return this:
return event.data.ref.set({test}, {merge: true});

which is basically same thing. Both fail.
Btw, I followed firebase docs and  makeuppercase function gives me the same error.
From the docs:
// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:documentId/original
// and saves an uppercased version of the message
// to /messages/:documentId/uppercase
exports.makeuppercase = onDocumentCreated("/messages/{documentId}", (event) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
  const original = event.data.data().original;

  // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `event.params`
  logger.log("Uppercasing", event.params.documentId, original);

  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();

  // You must return a Promise when performing
  // asynchronous tasks inside a function
  // such as writing to Firestore.
  // Setting an 'uppercase' field in Firestore document returns a Promise.
  return event.data.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});

How can I fix this issue?

The error is telling you that event.data.value is undefined.  What value are you expecting it to have?  Also note that the example code you provide calls event.data.data() to get document data from the passed event, but you're not doing that in your code at all.  Are you sure you're doing the right thing here?  You might also want to review the full documentation for Firestore triggers to get more information and example on how they work.

Well I am getting the same error even if I don't try to access event.data.value, for example this is a code almost exactly like the one from the documentation you send, and it still gives me the exact same error:
exports.tester = onDocumentCreated(
{region: functionsRegion},
"messages/{documentId}",
(event) => {
logger.log("Inside tester function");
const snapshot = event.data;
if (!snapshot) {
console.log("No data associated with the event");
return;
}
const data = snapshot.data();
logger.log(data);
});

So that makes me think that issue is probably somewhere else.

Okay, after reading the error message and documentation thoroughly I found the issue - this is how I was passing in the region.
The error message was pointing to a code in library: /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore.js:297:115
That's the function that was giving an error:
function onOperation(eventType, documentOrOpts, handler) {
    const { document, database, namespace, opts } = getOpts(documentOrOpts);
    // wrap the handler
    const func = (raw) => {
        const event = raw;
        const documentPattern = new path_pattern_1.PathPattern(typeof document === "string" ? document : document.value());
        const params = makeParams(event.document, documentPattern);
        const firestoreEvent = makeFirestoreEvent(eventType, event, params);
        return (0, trace_1.wrapTraceContext)((0, onInit_1.withInit)(handler))(firestoreEvent);
    };
    func.run = handler;
    func.__endpoint = makeEndpoint(eventType, opts, document, database, namespace);
    return func;
}
exports.onOperation = onOperation;

Particularly this line: new path_pattern_1.PathPattern(typeof document === "string" ? document : document.value())
So that made me realize that the document is not being properly passed.
SOLUTION:
I searched the docs and found how you properly pass the region:
const functionsRegion = "europe-west1"; //pass your region here

exports.tester = onDocumentCreated(
    {
      document: "messages/{documentId}",
      region: functionsRegion,
    },
    "collection_name/{documentId}",
    (event) => {
     // rest of your code
    });

All works now. Case closed :)
